# What does target and object mean in assignment statements?

Tags: python, variable-assignment, immutability, mutable

https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#module-copy

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create
> bindings between a **target** and an **object**. For collections that are
> mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one
> can change one copy without changing the other.

If I have the following code:

```
variable1 = 'a string'
```

Is `variable1` the *target* and `a string` the *object*, or what do these 2 terms refer to?

**I don't want to make a specific code or solve anything**, just understand the documentation, I am a beginner student in Python.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-forms-of-assignment-statements-in-python/

TL:DR Yes. This info is easy to find. One key skill as developer is searching for information. So try a bit to find it on your own next time.

Comment: Hi @Raphael, I did it, but in the documentation I was surprised by the terminology used

Comment: @gus  The reason they refer to it as "the object" is because **everything** in Python is an instance of a class, including the primitive datatypes (int, bool, float, None, etc), functions, methods and classes.  Examples:   `type(5) # <class 'int'>` , `type(int) # <class 'type'>` where `type` is the base metaclass of all classes, `type(len) #<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>`

Comment: Hi @nigh_anxiety, I knew that, what confused me was the term "target" in this context.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the target is a variable, and a value is the object. A target is *binded* to a variable. For extra context, the copy module creates a new object so you can change one without affecting another.

Comment: For completeness, the target can be a name (`a`), an indexed expressions (`a[3]`), an attribute (`a.bar`) or a comma-separated sequence of any of these three. (The sequence can also be wrapped in parentheses or brackets, without implying anything about tuples, lists, etc.)

Comment: By "comma-separated sequence" you mean, for example, a `list`, right? @chepner

Comment: It looks like a list, but it isn't, really. `[a, b] = 1, 2` doesn't create a list anywhere: the *tuple* `1, 2` is created but immediately unpacked into the two names `a` and `b`; `a, b = ...` and `(a, b) = ...` would behave identically. The parentheses/brackets are just for show.

Comment: Ok, now I get it, I thought you meant a list @chepner